# Any keyword or methods in Java similar to Go's Select?

Tags: java, select, go

Is there any keyword or methods in Java that is similar to Go's **select** statement, that is only used for selection of communication channels?

Comment: You can use `switch` statement in Java

Comment: I was wondering if there are other options besides switch?

Comment: This is other solution [Alternative to Switch Case in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425659/alternative-to-switch-case-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers misunderstand the question (or they don't know what `select` is in Go).

Go does have a [`switch`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) *and* a [`select`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) statement, where the `switch` is the rough equivalent of Java's `switch`, and the `select` statement is similar to `switch` but only to select on *communication operations* (the cases are comm. ops.: a [send](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) statement or a [receive](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) operation).

Java does not have an equivalent to Go's `select`. You can achieve the same but in a more verbose way, and it's not built into the language like Go's `select`.

See related questions:

[Concurrency Java example of Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060277/concurrency-java-example-of-go)

[Equivalent of golang channel in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561110/equivalent-of-golang-channel-in-java)

[Go channel vs Java BlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690403/go-channel-vs-java-blockingqueue)

Answer (score 0):

The similar syntax in Java is **switch**.
For detail, you could refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html.

```
switch (month) {
    case 1:  monthString = "January";
             break;
    case 2:  monthString = "February";
             break;
    default: monthString = "Invalid month";
             break;

}
```